# How can I save bitmap file without any compression

Tags: c#, .net-core, bmp

I want to save bitmap file (C# core) without any compression at all.

Is there any way doing so?

i.e. I am using magickImage, and try to save with bitdepth = 24 (that's for RGB number of bits), put one pixel with RGB:

For red: hexa 79 (121 dec), green: 7A hex, blue: 7B hex.

When I open it as binary, i.e by:

> https://www.onlinehexeditor.com/

I don't see those value (79 hex, 7a hex, and 7b hex).

Is there any way to save that image with the exact rgb values?

Also, I intend to split very big image file to small parts (can be 100K x 100K pixels) , with a fast and easy way to merge them together.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you post come code?

Comment: Bitmap is raw format. it is not compressed. Secondly you won't be able to merge 100k by 100k pixel images. one image like that will take around 40 gb of ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert this to C# easily, but why not just save it without molesting it at all?

```
Private Shared Function ConvertImageBasic(filepath As String) As String

    Try

        'Open image
        Dim sourceImg As Bitmap = New Bitmap(filepath)

        'Set new path for the converted image
        filepath = IO.Path.GetTempPath & "image.bmp"

        'Save opened image as a bitmap file type
        sourceImg.Save(filepath, ImageFormat.Bmp)

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox("Failed to convert image, " & ex.Message, vbRetryCancel)

    End Try

    ConvertImageBasic = filepath
End Function
```

You can also just save it with ImageMagick.

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(filepath))
{
    image.Format = MagickFormat.Bmp;
    image.Write("Snakeware.bmp");
}
```

As far as appending images, take a look at these:

```
MagickImageCollection.AppendHorizontally()
MagickImageCollection.AppendVertically()
```

Comment: I saw that it shall be with true-color. bitmap is not the most comressed, until it is true-color.

Comment: You said you wanted it uncompressed, which can be interpreted as the raw bitmap.